# Silverlight refresh an Image depending on a variable stored in IsolatedStorage

Tags: c#, silverlight, image, isolatedstorage

I'm pretty new in silverlight and I have some problems with my application.I keep the application date in database and in IsolatedStorage.

I have an Image control on the top of the UI where the user can always see the application current date.I'm using image because I've created some stylish images to represent the date in  mm.yyyy format.

I set the URI of the image control in mainpage Authentication_LoggedIn():

```
   //setez luna curenta in isolatedStorage
   adminUtilizContext.GetSetariParticulare(4, 0, (op) =>
   {
        foreach (var item in op.Value)
        {
            if (IsolatedStorageSettings.ApplicationSettings.Contains("lunaCurenta"))
                IsolatedStorageSettings.ApplicationSettings["lunaCurenta"] = item.Substring(2);
            else
                IsolatedStorageSettings.ApplicationSettings.Add("lunaCurenta", item.Substring(2));

            Uri uri;
            uri = new Uri("/Indeco.SIEF;component/Images/Calendar/"+item.Substring(2)+".png", UriKind.RelativeOrAbsolute);
            dataLuna.Source = new BitmapImage(uri);                    
        }
    }, null);
```

The xaml looks like this:

```
    <StackPanel Grid.Column="1" Orientation="Horizontal" HorizontalAlignment="Right">                
        <Image  Name="dataLuna" HorizontalAlignment="Right"/>                                
    </StackPanel>
```

It works fine, but the problem appears when the user changes the current date. In database and IsolatedStorage is stored correctly. I'm changing the image source but the new image doesn't appear until I manually refresh the page.

Can you please tell me how can I do this automatically without having to manually refresh the page!

Best regards.

The code where the user changes the date is in ViewModel(CurrentConfigurationViewModel.cs) of the coresponding UI(CurrentConfigurations.xaml).There is a combobox with the months and SelectedItemChanged automatically updates the database and the IsolatedStorage.That's where I've put the code you saw in my previous comment.There is a NumericUpDown control for the year too that works the same.But for now let's talk about the month and after that i'll do it for the year myself:D!
thank's again
[image: A print screen with the change date UI and the code i wrote for updating the Image source for the up-right corner (date)]
As you can see in this picture when the user logged in the application date was april 2011(up right) and after I modify the month it stil displays the old date and I verified in the Db, in isolated storage and it seems to be ok.There you can see the code I wrote to update the Image source too.

Comment: +1 for supplying code/Xaml and good detail.

Answer (score 2):

You could try to set up a Property which holds the image and then bind the Image Source to this property. Your class needs to implement INotifyPropertyChanged interface and then you can inform your Image control that your Property Changed and it will reload the Image.
I hope this helps. :)

If that's your code then you are generating a whole new MainPage and setting it's dataLuna ImageSource, and not the original pages dataLuna controls.

I'm happy i could help.

Comment: Setting the ImageSource directly from code-behind, as they have, should work the same way as a binding (it's just old-school code instead of MVVM style). Looks like the cause of the problem is something else.

Comment: Update your question with the real answer (from your comment) and I will upvote it (and delete my own answer). Amazing how simple it is when you see the actual code :)

Comment: Yes you are right if you see the code and know what it supposed to do and what it actually does it is lot easier to correct it. :)

Answer (score 1):

My suggestion would be to fire an event from the page/control where the date change happens. In the main page you can subscribe to the event and reload the image. Hope this helps.

Comment: The problem here was a simple newbie error: - creating a new instance of a page, assigning a value to a property, then throwing the whole page away :)

Answer (score 0):

Hi all of you guys and thanks again for you're interest!I've solved my problem like that:

```
 var mp = ((Application.Current.RootVisual as ContentControl).Content as UserControl).Content as Indeco.SIEF.MainPage;
        Debug.Assert(mp != null); 

 Uri uri;
 uri = new Uri("/Indeco.SIEF;component/Images/Calendar/" + id.ToString() + ".png", UriKind.RelativeOrAbsolute);
 mp.dataLuna.Source = new BitmapImage(uri);
```